# issue is with clone, splice, remove, append jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are multiple images in HTML.

```
<ul class="ice-navigator">
<li>
    <a  href="javascript:void(0);" class="thumb" id = "26"> 
        <img src="images/123.png" alt="Title #0" width="75" height="75"/>
    </a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="thumb" id = "28">
        <img src="images/456.png" alt="Title #0" width="75" height="75"/>
    </a>

</li>
.
.
.

</ul>
```

I want to show only 5 images at a time, so i am using this code "onload" to hide image if it is more than 5.

```
stPt = 0, elToShow = 5; //showing 5 elements
$ul = $('ul.ice-navigator');

    $li = $('ul.ice-navigator li'); //get the list of li's
$copy_li = [];
copy_lgt = $li.length - elToShow;

for (var i = elToShow; i < $li.length; i++) 
{
  var tmp;
  tmp = $li.eq(i);
  $copy_li.push(tmp.clone());
  tmp.remove();
}
```

To show prev and next, i am using this code.

```
$('.ice-next').click (function () 
{
    $li = $('ul.ice-navigator li'); //get the list of li's
    $copy_li.splice(copy_lgt, 0, $li.eq(0).clone() ); //move the 1st element clone to the last position in copy_li
    $li.eq(0).remove(); //kill the 1st element in the UL
    $ul.append($copy_li.shift()); //add to the last
});

$('.ice-previous').click (function () 
{
    $li = $('ul.ice-navigator li'); //get the list of li's
    $copy_li.splice(0, 0, $li.eq(elToShow-1).clone()); //move the 1st element clone to the last position in copy_li
    $li.eq(elToShow-1).remove();//kill the 1st element in the UL
    $ul.prepend($copy_li.pop());//add to the last

});
```

Everything works fine, except this:

There is one click event associated with thumb class.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".thumb").click(function(){
    alert ("Reaching here");
)};
)}:
```

This is working in beginning. but once we have used

```
$('.ice-previous').click (function () or $('.ice-next').click (function ()
```

then 
    $(".thumb").click(function(){ is not working.

I mean now click on image will not print Reaching here.

What is causing this issue??

Answer (score 0):

Because you are removing and re-attaching DOM elements, you need to delegate your events on those elements like this:

```
$('.ice-navigator').on('click', '.thumb', function() {
    alert('Reaching here');
});
```

More info: http://api.jquery.com/on/